Chrome Kiosk mode allows you to exit by tapping and holding on touch screen
We are using a large touchscreen with an web app we have created that has an interactive canvas. I have managed to disable most touch features, such as context menu and zoom etc, but one issue remains, when tapping and holding, the following close icon appears.

Which allows you to exit kiosk mode. It kind of defeats the entire purpose of kiosk mode to be honest. Anyone encountered this issue and managed to hide this button? Have done some searching and found references to:
Locate the experimental-fullscreen-exit-ui entry and disable.
In Chrome flags but this no longer exists and seems to have been removed around 2019 or whereabouts.
Have tried preventing default on taphold, adding touch-callout disablement in CSS.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
